# How to get correct index in filter JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have duplicate data into array and I am trying to fetch index of each element using indexOf. but, it always give index of first record

```
var data = ["a","b","c","d","a",'c',"a"];
var filterData = data.filter(i=>i == "a");
filterData.forEach(element=>{
    var index = data.indexOf(element);
  console.log(index);
});
```

// Expected Answer : 0, 4, 6
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1ttn4m?file=index.ts

How do I get correct index of each element from original array.

Comment: To get the current index, you can use the second parameter `(element, index) => { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Add forEach to data too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by keeping track of where the previous element was found at.  Using that value, you can skip past those elements when finding the next index.

```js
var data = ["a","b","c","d","a",'c',"a"];
var filterData = data.filter(i => i == "a");
var previousIndex = -1;

filterData.forEach(element=>{
  var index = data.slice(++previousIndex).indexOf(element);
  console.log(index + previousIndex);
  previousIndex += index;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On `Array.forEach`, The default format is `arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg])`.

You can know more on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var data = ["a","b","c","d","a",'c',"a"];

data.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (element === 'a') {
    console.log(index);
  }
});
```

Comment: Derek your answer is correct. buy my array has more than 3000+ element and it is not good option to run foreach on that record and match.

Comment: But to get the duplicated indexes, it will be needed to review one by one and it won't take much time.

Comment: Getting all occurrences of a value in an array is linear at best. Maybe use a different data structure and reformulate the problem--your question doesn't provide any context about the number of elements or use case so you can't expect answers to address anything beyond what you asked about.